Kafka connecting to the same broker which is down for meta data reqeusts
So, I have an API that is hit after every 5 seconds. The API describes the topic in the request params, gets the starting and ending offset and then gets all the messages within the range. Later it also calls the subscription method of the kafka admin client to get the consumer group info. I have around 4 bootstrap brokers, recently I observed that, kafka re-connected with the same broker which was down for about an hour and keep failing. How to make sure that kafka re-tries with some other broker in the boostrap server? There is another issue. I have a service that is a short lived process. It is an autosys job. It starts a process at a specific time say morning 3:30 AM. All it does is produce a message on a topic. As we know that kafka producer fetches the meta data request of the topic before producing the message as it needs to know the broker that is leader of the topic partition. If, kafka decided to connect with one of the broker that is down, it will wait for max.block.ms and fail. How to ensure that kafka retries with other boostrap brokers before failing?
I actually do not know what to do for the #1 problem. For, #2 I know we can tweak properties like metadata.max.age.ms, although I feel it should be multiple of request.timemout.ms as it would allow it to retry.
